# asyncio gather yielding results as they come in

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I want to be able to yield results from a set of tasks run by `gather` as they come in for further processing.

```py
# Not real code, but an example

async for response in asyncio.gather(*[aiohttp.get(url) for url in ['https://www.google.com', 'https://www.amazon.com']]):
    await process_response(response)
```

At present, I can use the `gather` method to run all `get` concurrently, but must wait until they're all complete to process them. I'm still new to Python async/await, so maybe there's some obvious way of doing this I'm missing.

```py
# What I can do now
responses = await asyncio.gather(*[aiohttp.get(url) for url in ['https://www.google.com', 'https://www.amazon.com']])
await asyncio.gather(*[process_response(response) for response in responses])
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`gather` as you already noted will wait until all coroutines are done, thus you need to find another way.

For example you can use function [asyncio.as_completed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.as_completed) that seems to do exactly what you want.

```
import asyncio


async def echo(t):
    await asyncio.sleep(t)
    return t



async def main():
    coros = [
        echo(3),
        echo(2),
        echo(1),
    ]

    for first_completed in asyncio.as_completed(coros):
        res = await first_completed
        print(f'Done {res}')


asyncio.run(main())
```

Result:

```
Done 1
Done 2
Done 3
[Finished in 3 sec]
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to be what I want, thanks. I noticed that for many cases, the difference between `as_completed` and `gather` can be pretty thin and sometimes `gather` has the upper hand. That was an unexpected result, and worth noting.

Comment: @AlejandroWainzinger *the difference between as_completed and gather can be pretty thin* That should be the case only if the coroutines take similar times to run. If there is considerable difference among the coroutines' run times, `as_completed` should produce the results of the faster ones much sooner than `gather`, which always waits for them all before returning anything.